# MEAN.io Strange $http.get Response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am trying to develop a user management feature for a website using the MEAN.io stack. What I'm trying to do has worked in the past for other models on the same site so I'm not sure what is going on. My issue is that I am trying to get all the User models from the MongoDB database and pass them to an AngularJS controller so that I can display their information on a user management page. To that end, I added this function to the User controller in the backend:

```
exports.readUsers = function(req, res) {
    var decodedToken = req.decodeToken;
    var User = mongoose.model('User');
    var id = req.params.id;
    existUser(decodedToken, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            return sendError(res, 'INVALID_TOKEN');
        }
        User.find({})
            .select('username')
            .exec(function(err, results) {
               if(err) {
                 return sendError(res, err);
               }
               res.json({success: true, userList: results});
         });
     });
}
```

This line to the routing code:

```
router.get('/users/all', Authorization.token, user.readUsers);
```

And this AngularJS controller for use with the frontend:

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  var app = angular.module("GAP");

  app.factory("UserEditFactory", function UserEditFactory($http, API_URL, AuthTokenFactory, $q) {
    "use strict";
    return {
      readUsers: readUsers          
    };

    //Get all users in the DB                                                                                                                                                                                      
    function readUsers() {
      if(AuthTokenFactory.getToken()) {
        return $http.get(API_URL + "/users/all");
      }else {
        return $q.reject({
          data: "valid token required"
        });
      }
    }



  });

  app.controller("userPageController", ["UserEditFactory", "$scope", "$http", "$window", "API_URL",
       function(UserEditFactory, $scope, $http, $window, API_URL) {
           UserEditFactory.readUsers().then(function(data) {
               console.log(data.data);
               $scope.users = data.data.userList;
           }, function(response) {
               console.log(response);
           });
        }
   ]);
})();
```

When I load the page that is supposed to display this information, no data is displayed. I have determined that the AngularJS controller is calling the second function which I understand is the one used to respond to an error.

Further investigation of the object returned by the $http.get call reveals no data, and a status of -1. I'm not sure why this is happening, because I have used this exact pattern of code to get and display data from other models in the database on the same site. I can manually make HTTP calls to those working functions from this controller, and everything works fine. I'm not sure where to go from here or how to learn more about the issue. Can anyone offer insight? Let me know if you need more information.

**Edit:** As requested, here is the code for the AuthTokenFactory, which is an app.factory object in a common JS file.

```js
  app.factory('AuthTokenFactory', function AuthTokenFactory($window) {
        'use strict';
        var store = $window.localStorage;
        var tokenKey = 'auth-token';
 var userKey = "username";

        return {
            getToken: getToken,
            setToken: setToken,
            setUsername: setUsername
 };

        function getToken() {
            return store.getItem(tokenKey);
 }

        function setToken(token) {
            if (token) {
                store.setItem(tokenKey, token);
            } else {
  store.removeItem(tokenKey);
            }
        }

        function setUsername(username) {
            if (username) {
                store.setItem(userKey, username);
            } else {
                store.removeItem(userKey);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is `AuthTokenFactory.getToken()`? Is it a `$resource` object? Or does it depend on a `$resource` object? We need to see the code for that.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by $resource object, but I have added the AuthTokenFactory code to the original post. Let me know if you need anything else.